# Tree representation of the search process for puzzle

Tags: algorithm, optimization, prolog, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I am supposed to put 1 large and 3 small boxes on the shelves as in the picture bellow, **using minimum amount of energy**.

[image]

The large box has twice the length and weight of the small one. The length of the shelves is three times the length of a small box. The upper shelve is positioned at twice the height of the lower one.

How I can represent the tree of the search process(ex. using Uinform-cost search) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this using Constraint Logic Programming (here [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org)).  You model the problem with variables ranging over a numeric domain, and invoke a built-in search routine.  For simplicity, I have assumed length=weight.

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(branch_and_bound).

solve(Vars, Energy) :-

    Vars = [TopSmall, TopLarge, BotSmall, BotLarge],

    TopSmall :: 0..3,                       % how many small boxes on top
    BotSmall :: 0..3,                       % how many small boxes on bottom
    TopLarge :: 0..1,                       % how many large boxes on top
    BotLarge :: 0..1,                       % how many large boxes on bottom

    TopSmall + BotSmall #= 3,               % total small boxes
    TopLarge + BotLarge #= 1,               % total large boxes

    TopWeight #= TopSmall*1 + TopLarge*2,   % total on top
    BotWeight #= BotSmall*1 + BotLarge*2,   % total on bottom

    TopWeight #=< 3,                        % shelf capacities
    BotWeight #=< 3,

    Energy #= 2*TopWeight + 1*BotWeight,    % Top shelf at double height

    minimize(labeling(Vars), Energy).       % find a minimal solution
    % labeling(Vars).                       % alternatively, find all solutions
```